# Как верстать сайт, который дизайн как одна картина

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, возможно я не правильно выразил вопрос, дело в том что есть есть сайт, на котором элементы дизайна не должны выходить за пределы размера браузера ([http://василийпупкин.рф/](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%84/) нив коем случае это не реклама). Мучаюсь уже очень давно, как сделать так чтоб во всех мониторах сайт смотрелся нормально. Сейчас на больших экранах (15-17-21 дюйм) нормально смотрится а на маленьких экранах (айпад, нетбук) шрифты не читабельны, потому что размеры шрифтов заданы на % от размера браузера, для того чтоб всё было пропорционально, и в конце такой результат печальный. Вообщем такой вопрос как верстать такие дизайны, так чтоб во всех экранах было нормально. Данное время все размеры элементов сайта (шрифты, картинки) зависит от размера браузера(autoresize), дайте советы, материалы и т.д. За ранее спасибо всем.

p.s. Я читал статьи про резиновые сайты, но там не такие дизайны, и они мне не очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [Media Queries](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/) и для айпадов/нетбуков прописывайте размер шрифтов больше ( а может даже и строго в пикселях).

Answer (score 2):

1) Определитесь как будет сайт выглядеть на всех экранах. Если не в состоянии это сделать мысленно, используйте специальные плагины с линейкой или ограничивающий DIV, у которого overflow будет стоять scroll.
1.1) Если на самом маленьком все помещается, то дальше можете не читать.
1.2) Если влезает не все - выберите наиболее значимые элементы. Остальные скрывайте при помощи [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) или яваскриптом(хуже)
1.3) Резиновость и floatовость вас тут весьма выручат, но еще больше выручит отключение стилей текста, особенно, шрифтов: не будет фэйла на каком-нибудь айфоне, который не воспринял должным образом кастомный шрифт.
1.4) КОгда сайт приведен в нормальное состояние, верните обратно максимальную ширину(про ритину не забудте. И про приближающийся QFHD)